# How to setup scene for Isometric workflow? In order to import 2D ISO image to make it in 3D

Tags: modeling, camera, units, world

You know we can make 2D isometric renders of 3D images, right? I want to do the reverse; I import an isometric image and want to use it to create the 3D model. An illustration of the work I'm trying to do, I've setup the camera (rotation xyz 60,0,45) and I've created some cubes to work with to see in wireframe:

[image: Illustration with 2D image and 3D cube with array]

My problem is, once the correct camera setup is done, the grid isn't set up correctly. I mean that the height of 1 is not corresponding with the grid and the closest I have is 0.81673, you can look the image below. The cubes aren't seized precisely and when I Ctrl+move the increment is 1 and not of the height of the cube;

[image: Image showing two cubes on a tiled isometric grid of camera angle 60 degrees, one of the cube perfectly aligned with the grid but with a wrong height, and the other with a good height but not aligned to grid]

My questions;

1. How to find the correct size for my cubes?
2. How to setup the world to work with that isometric height non equel to 1?
3. What is the best workflow to achieve the result I want, recreating in 3D a 2D isometric images (moreover if I'm going the wrong way) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why don't you want to set the camera to XYZ 54.73, 0, 45?

Comment: Because those who made the game I took the image from (Arcanum, from Troika, 2001) used a XYZ60,0,45 projection, and by using XYZ54.73,0,45 I'm not in the correct grid. Also my long term project would be remaking part of the game in 3D, that's why I'm using 60.0.45 otherwise I can't rebuild their world

Answer (score 1):

Step 01

### Blend file - Dimetry

- Set camera Dimetry (54.563/0/45) with dimension of your ISO-image
- Increase camera dimension on Y axis *1.150
- Add your image as Camera Background Image
- Build your models and save

Step 02

### Blend file - Isometry

- Set camera Isometry (60/0/45)
- Add Empty
- Link Collection (or Scene) done in Dimetry
- Parent link to Empty
- Scale Empty on Z axis 0.81673
- Render

Like that you can anytime to switch into correctly measured models in Dimetry, but just by opening Isometric file re-render for final output.